# Whats the best build system for building a database?

Tags: sql, database, build-process

This is a problem that I come to on occasion and have yet to work out an answer that I'm happy with. I'm looking for a build system that works well for building a database - that is running all of the SQL files in the correct database instance as the correct user and in the correct order, and handling dependencies and the like properly.

I have a system that I hacked together using Gnu Make and it works, but it's not especially flexable and frankly can be a bit of a pain to work with in some situations. I've considered looking at things like SCons and CMake too, but I don't know how much better they are likely to be, or if there's a better system out there that already exists...

Comment: Which database platform? MySQL, MSSQL, Postgres, Oracle, something else?

Comment: Postgres primarially for myself, but it was more of a general curiosity which is why I left it open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a shell script that runs all the create statements and imports in the proper order. You may also find [migrations](http://garrettsnider.backpackit.com/pub/367902) (comes with rails) interesting. It provides a `make` like infrastructure that let's you maintain a database the structure of which evolves over time.

Say you add a new column to some table. In migrations you'd write a snippet of code which describes the requirements for adding the column and also to rollback the change so you can switch to different versions of your schema automatically.

I'm not a big fan of the tight integration with rails, though, but the principles behind it are very interesting.

Comment: I think it's fairer to say that Rails is (somewhat) tightly integrated with ActiveRecord. Not completely, other ORMs are possible, and Rails3/Merb2 will open the space up greatly. ActiveRecord can quite comfortably be used on its own.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. I guess what I meant was that you wouldn't be using it to manage a database schema that has no ruby/active record/rails dependancies otherwise. I'd like to see a "general purpose" migrations like tool. Which sounds a little like what the poster is asking about.

Comment: I've been playing with them, and Migrations seem like a really nice clever way of handling this. Can just ignore the rest of the rails stuff that gets bundled with it for now too :)

Comment: I voted this answer down as a shell script with commands in order is useful for small databases, but doesn't scale well. Migrations looks like  a lot of overhead to apply to an existing project ... any other contenders?

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, I just use a batch file with SQLCMD.EXE and a bunch of .SQL files. It's not perfect, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

For my database, I use Migrator.NET
This is a .NET framework which allows you to create classes in where you define your DDL statements.
The framework comes with a command-line tool with which you can execute your 'migrations' in the correct order.
It also has a msbuild - task, so you can integrate it in a continuous integration build as well.

Answer (score 0):

First export full DDL files describing all tables, views, source code
(procedures, functions, packages), sequences, and grants of a DB schema

See
[Is there a tool to generate a full database DDL for SQL Server? What about Postgres and MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929815/is-there-a-tool-to-generate-a-full-database-ddl-for-sql-server-what-about-postg)

I created a database build system (part SQL-parser, part make file) to put these files together in a DB creation script using python.